# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1)) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Scaffold called contracts and a Model called Addresses. I want to add call my model in the scaffold.
in the Contrato.rb (Model) I have:

```
class Contrato < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['estado', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'endereco', 'cep'].blank?}

  before_save do
    self.paf.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("paf")
  end
end
```

When I try to create a Contract using the console using:
`Contrato.create!(razao: "Carrefour Comercial", cpnj: "12141618", insc_estadual: "12345", insc_municipal: "56789", paf: "", empresa: "Carrefour", addresses_attributes:[{estado: "Sc", cidade: "santos", bairro: "myborough", endereco: "avenue", cep: "112233"})` The rails controller returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):8
        1: from app/models/contrato.rb:3:in `block in <class:Contrato>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1))
```

I'm clueless about this error.

Comment: can you provide the first 10ish lines of `contracto.rb`?

Comment: I already provided. It's just those lines.

Comment: `[]` is expected to be called with a single argument, you're passing 5, hence the error. If you're able to access every key/value for each `addresses_attributes`, you can check them with something like `attrs.values.any?(&:blank?)`.

Comment: You are missing a ``]`` to close the array of ``address_attributes``.

Comment: I solved it was a problem in the Controller. And I removed the ```lambda```and changed for ```reject_if: all_blank```Thanks for your support lads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved adding

```
def contrato_params
      params.require(:contrato).permit(:razao, :cpnj, :insc_estadual,:insc_municipal, :empresa, paf:[], addresses_attributes:[:estado, :cidade, :bairro, :endereco, :cep])
end
```

The addresses_attributes to the contracts controller.

Answer (score 0):

In above code

```
class Contrato < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['estado', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'endereco', 'cep'].blank?}

  before_save do
    self.paf.gsub!(/[\[\]\"]/, "") if attribute_present?("paf")
  end
end
```

At line of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` it should be like

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs.any? { |k, v| ['estado', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'endereco', 'cep'].include?(k) && v.blank? } }
```